# MySql to Wordpress Query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to count the number of value 1 from wp_ul_locked on wp_usermeta i try this code

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE 'wp_ul_locked'");
```

or

`$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = '1'")`;

or

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->usermeta LIKE 'wp_ul_locked' WHERE meta_value = '1'");
```

in this mode return count of all wp_ul_locked not only value 1

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'wp_ul_locked' = '1' ");
```

but return empty or error

[image: example of table]

Where is my error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is wrong. Try this:

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) from $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'wp_ul_locked' AND meta_value=1 ")
```

Comment: $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) from $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'wp_ul_locked' AND meta_value = '1' "); this work i have removed only ''.. thanks so much!

Comment: Corrected the synthax mistake. Feel free to accept the answer if it solved the problem ;)

Comment: Fabio you're italian?

Answer (score 5):

Well... you have an error on every of your test queries:

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE 'wp_ul_locked'");
```

You missed `FROM`

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = '1'");
```

This will return empty, the value of `meta_key` is never `1`

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->usermeta LIKE 'wp_ul_locked' WHERE meta_value = '1'");
```

This will not work, you put `LIKE` before `WHERE`

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'wp_ul_locked' = '1' ");
```

This will not work

The correct query will be this one i guess:

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'wp_ul_locked' AND meta_value = '1' ");
```

I changed LIKE with an equal, but you can put a `LIKE` instead of equal here `meta_key = 'wp_ul_locked'`